22.04 Dell Latitude 5550 locking itself after login
When waking from sleep and logging, the laptop's screen goes black after a moment (I have the time to launch the browser for example). The laptop appears unresponsive and eventually it "wakes" again presenting a locked session as if it just went back from sleep. It can do that for several times until it settles (2-3 times).
